# String Indices Must be Integers in Python

Tags: python, string

I am using Python to solve a contest problem. I am getting this error. I am fairly new and inexperienced with Python.

```
    for kek in sorteddic:
        lengthitem = int(len(kek))
        questionstring = start[0, lengthitem]
```

kek is essentially the "item" in "sorteddic" which is an array of strings.

The error I am getting is:

```
questionstring = start[0, lengthitem]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: you want `start[0:lengthitem]` it's a `:` instead of a `,`

Answer (score 1):

It's because the item you're trying to use as an index, `0, lengthitem`, is not an integer but a *tuple* of integers, as shown below:

```
>>> x = 1 : type(x)
<class 'int'>
>>> x = 1,2 : type(x)
<class 'tuple'>
```

If your intent is to get a slice of the array (not *entirely* clear but I'd warrant it's a fairly safe guess), the correct operator to use is `:`, as in:

```
questionstring = start[0:lengthitem]
```

or, since `0` is the default start point:

```
questionstring = start[:lengthitem]
```

The following transcript shows how your current snippet fails and the correct way to do it:

```
>>> print("ABCDE"[1])
B

>>> print("ABCDE"[1,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers

>>> print("ABCDE"[1:3])
BC
```

Answer (score 0):

Slice notation uses *colons*, not *commas* (unless you are in `numpy` where commas separate dimensions in slices, athough under the hood that is treated as a tuple of slice objects). So use:

```
questionstring = start[0:lengthitem]
```

Comment: Oh I knew that, just did not come to mind. Thanks for the reply.